# ASP Treeview control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

So I have an `asp:treeview` control on my website, but I want to change something about it. Below is what the `asp:treeview` generates for a given child node of the parent. I want to remove the

`<td> <div style="width:0px;height:1px"></div> </td>`

but I don't know exactly how (there is unnecessary spacing and I want to remove it). I did find a solution on StackOverflow for a possible solution. The solution was to place this in my .css page:

`.CategoryTreeView .TreeView table tbody tr td:first-child { display:none; }`.

while this somewhat worked, it took out the parent node and I was left with just children nodes. So instead of this:

```
All Products
    Evergreens
    Oaks
```

I was left with just:

```
Evergreens
Oaks
```

---- Parent Node Generated Code ----

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="NodeStyle RootNodeStyle SelectedNodeStyle"href="category.aspx?zcid=130" 
            id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_uxCategory_CATEGORIES_ctrlNavigationn0" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">All Products</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---- Children Node Generated Code ----

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="width:0px;height:1px"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="LeafNodeStyle" href="category.aspx?zcid=131" id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_uxCategory_CATEGORIES_ctrlNavigationn1" 
            style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Evergreens</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with:

`.CategoryTreeView div div div table tbody tr td:first-child {display: none; }`

And it worked for me.